# PHP login script SQL error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

I'm fairly new to SQL and PHP.

I'm trying to write a simple login script. I have a form in a HTML document that I have proved posts the correct data into the 2 variables required but my script fails when it executes the SQL...

I've also tested the SQL in mysqlWorkbench and I get the result I want ???

Please help.

Here is my script:

```
<?PHP

$odbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db('examresults', $odbc)  or die("Could not find database");

// username and password sent from form 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

$sql='SELECT * FROM tuser where username = '.$username.' and password = '.$password.'';

$result = mysql_query($sql, $odbc) or die ("Error in SQL");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 //If result matched username and password, table row must only equal 1 row
if($count==1)
{   
    header("location:exammenu.php");
}
else 
{
    echo 'username and password do not match';
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're new I recommend you stop using mysql_connect and (if you are familiar) look up mysqli instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: @Matastic You can use MySQL. But you should not use any PHP function whose name starts with `mysql_`.  Read [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for more information.

Comment: it dies instead of $result= mysql_query($sql, $odbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should not use them anymore. Your code is also vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Using `mysql_error` instead of just printing out "Error in SQL" would give us (and you) a more detailed sql error message. But most likely it is failing because you forgot to put `" "` around your strings in the query.

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM tuser where username = "'.$username.'" and password = "'.$password.'"';
```

Comment: thanks yeh ive been working with integers instead of strings and forgot you need "" around strings thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

The query should be as below:

```
 $sql='SELECT * FROM tuser where username = "'.$username.'" and password = "'.$password.'"';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're really going to need to use `mysql`, *at least sanitize* your input. Also note the quotes in the $sql variable. This should work (though not tested):

```
<?PHP

$odbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db('examresults', $odbc)  or die("Could not find database");

// username and password sent from form 
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'], $odbc); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'], $odbc); 

$sql=sprintf('SELECT * FROM tuser where username = "%s" and password = "%s"', $username, $password);

$result = mysql_query($sql, $odbc) or die ("Error in SQL");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 //If result matched username and password, table row must only equal 1 row
if($count==1)
{   
    header("location:exammenu.php");
}
else 
{
    echo 'username and password do not match';
}
```

I suggest using `sprintf` to format your sql statement to make it easier to spot such errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code. i think it will work correctly.

```
<?PHP

$odbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db('examresults', $odbc)  or die("Could not find database");

// username and password sent from form 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM tuser where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $odbc) or die ("Error in SQL");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 //If result matched username and password, table row must only equal 1 row
if($count==1)
{   
    header("location:exammenu.php");
}
else 
{
    echo 'username and password do not match';
}
?>
```